# What does a parallel port on an embedded system look like?

Tags: embedded

this may be a stupid question but it's been confusing me. 
I've been watching some videos on Embedded Systems and they're talking about parallel ports, the data, the direction and the amount used.
I understand that the ports are connected to wires which feed other parts of the system or external devices. But I am confused because the lecture I watched says that to control a single LED would require 1 bit from 1 port.

My question is, what does the parallel port on an embedded system look like and how would you connect your own devices to the board? (say you made a device which sent 4 random bits to the port)

EDIT: I have just started learning so I might have missed a vital piece of information which would tie this altogether. I just don't understand how you can have an 8 bit port and only use 1 bit of it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_port 
Though this may not be exactly what you are looking for.  From the question, I'm not quite sure what you want, so I went generic.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should know that the term "parallel port" can refer to a wide variety of connectors. People usually use the phrase to describe 25-pin connectors found on older PCs for peripherals like printers or modems, but they can have more or fewer pins than that. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_port) on them has some examples.

The LED example means that if you have an 8-bit parallel port, it will have 8 pins, so you would only need to connect one of the pins to an LED to be able to control it. The other pins don't disappear or anything strange, they can just be left unconnected. The rest of the pins will be either ones or zeros as well, *but it doesn't matter because they're not connected*. Writing a "1" or "0" to that one connected pin will drive the voltage high or low, which will turn the LED on or off, depending on how it's connected. You can write whatever you want to the other pins, and it won't affect the operation of the LED (though it would be safest to connect them to ground and write "0"s to them).

Here's an example:

```
// assume REG is a memory-mapped register that controls an 8-bit output
// port. The port is connected to an 8-pin parallel connector. Pin 0 is
// connected to an LED that will be turned on when a "1" is written to 
// Bit 0 (the least-significant bit) of REG

REG = 0x01 // write a "1" to bit 0, "0"s to everything else
```

I think your confusion stems from the phrase "we only need one bit", and I think it's a justified confusion. What they mean is that we only need to control that one bit on the port that corresponds to our LED to be able to manipulate the LED, but in reality, you can't write just one bit at a time, so it's a bit (ha!) misleading. You (probably) won't find registers smaller than 8-bits anymore, so you *do* have to read/write the registers in whole bytes at a time, but you can mask off the bits you don't care about, or do [read-modify-write](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2549952/2615940) cycles to avoid changing bits you don't intend to.

Comment: to add to this, sometimes the other pins are used, and you have to either do a read-modify-write to only change one of the pins, or sometimes the logic has various ways to let you only modify one bit at a time or not all the bits at once to make things like this easier.  but it varies widely you have to read the docs for the chip.

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering my question. One last thing to clarify. The port isn't actually a port like a serial or USB or legacy Parallel is it? It's hard wired in before you ever get to writing your program? So the LEDs and buttons would already be there because that's what the system was specified to be.so it's not like I would get an embedded system and plug in a keyboard and have to code the ports myself because it would connect to a USB or keyboard port?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly That will depend entirely on the system you're working with. Some will have controllers for the port so you can just write your data to registers to make them work, others may simply be wired connections that require you to implement the controllers from scratch yourself. I just finished a project where my chip had a VGA port connected, but no controller, so I had to code the VGA controller myself (I know: VGA isn't a parallel port, but the situation is analogous.) Another chip I worked with had a hardware UART controller (again, not parallel, but it's the same idea)...

Comment: @JamesDonnelly ... so I could just write my data to registers and it would handle the protocol-level signal changes and handshaking for me. You'll have to look at the documentation for your system to see if you need to implement the port controller or not. Also, if you're using an embedded OS like an embedded Linux distribution, you can probably use Linux system calls or standard libraries to handle your communication over the port.

Answer (score 0):

Without the context of a verbatim transcript of the videos in question, it is probably not possible to be precise about what they may have specifically referred to.

The term "parallel port" historically commonly refers to ports primarily intended for printer connections on a PC, conforming to the IEEE 1284 standard; the term distinguishing it from the "serial port" also used in some cases for printer connections but for two-way data communications in general.  More generally however it can refer to any port carrying multiple simultaneous data bits on multiple conductors.  In this sense that includes SDIO, SCSI, IDE, GPIB to name but a few, and even the processor's memory data bus is an example of a parallel port.

Most likely in the context of embedded systems in general, it may refer to a word addressed GPIO port, although it is not a particularly useful or precise term.  Typically on microcontrollers GPIO (general purpose I/O) ports are word addressable (typically 8, 16, or 32 bits wide), all bits of a single GPIO port may be written simultaneously (or in *parallel*), with all bit edges synchronised so their states are set simultaneously.

Now in the case where you only want to access a single bit of a GPIO (to control an LED for example), some GPIO blocks allow single but access by having separate set/clear registers, while others require read-modify-write semantics of the entire port. ARM Cortex-M supports "bit-banding" which is an alternate address space where every word address corresponds to a single bit in the physical address space.

However bit access of a GPIO port is not the same as a *serial port*; that refers to a port where multiple data bits are sent one at a time, as opposed to multiple data bits simultaneously.

Moreover the terms parallel-port and serial-port imply some form of block or stream data transfer as opposed to control I/O where each bit controls one thing, such as your example of the LED on/off - there the LED is not "receiving data" it is simply being switched on and off.  This is normally referred to as *digital I/O* (or DIO).  In this context you might refer to a *digital I/O port*; a term that distinguishes it from *analogue I/O* where the voltage on the pin can be set or measured as opposed to just two states high/low.