# Why does STM32 "Standard Peripheral Library" use a tmpreg variable instead of just setting the bits directly in the register?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

This is related to STM32 pre-HAL "Standard Peripheral Library"...

Why use tmpreg in the following code (taken from ADC functions)?

`

```
/* Get the old register value */
  tmpreg = ADCx->CR1;
  
  /* Clear the Analog watchdog channel select bits */
  tmpreg &= CR1_AWDCH_RESET;
  
  /* Set the Analog watchdog channel */
  tmpreg |= ADC_Channel;
  
  /* Store the new register value */
  ADCx->CR1 = tmpreg;
```

`

Why not just do this? What are the benefits / drawbacks of each?

```
/* Clear the Analog watchdog channel select bits */
  ADCx->CR1 &= CR1_AWDCH_RESET;
  
  /* Set the Analog watchdog channel */
  ADCx->CR1 |= ADC_Channel;
```

Thanks.

Using SPL as a reference for developing own drivers.

Comment: `Using SPL as a reference for developing own drivers.`

***Very bad reference.***

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest better references?

Comment: The version with the tempreg can also save lots of memory and additional read/write latency issues. 1. r-m-m-w vs 2. r-m-w+r-m-w

Comment: Thanks @kesselhaus. So is the first example, the better (cleaner) more efficient way to code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sloppy, dangerous and slow to write to the same hardware register over and over. Since all hardware registers must be `volatile` qualified, the compiler cannot optimises consecutive writes to the same register. This means that the code will get needlessly slow and might have possible side-effects such as the first write clearing a flag etc, changing the meaning of the code.

In your first example, all of the writes to `tmpreg` will get optimized and nothing will get written to the actual register. When everything is set, the register will only get written to once, in a single instruction. This is good practice.

In your second example, the register is accessed by read-modify-write 2 times in a row. It is needlessly slow and might cause side effects, for absolutely nothing gained. So it is bad code.

Also check out [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290)

Comment: This is also a good reference to follow up on other answers [why is read modify write necessary for registers on embedded systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549952/why-is-read-modify-write-necessary-for-registers-on-embedded-systems)

Answer (score 4):

Your first example does 1 write to the peripheral register. The second does 2.

They may both work, but they are not the same. When making a single write to the register, both changes will be made together, atomically. Whereas making 2 means that you'll change one option along with all its side-effects, then you'll change the other option. Their order may be important.

Comment: Not just order and side-effects, bit also the potential for interruption or context switch and consequent thread safety and timing - perhaps worth mentioning explicitly?

Comment: Thanks. Question regarding the "potential for interruption"... if the register changes after the tmpreg in the first example, it would be overwritten when the tmpreg variable is copied back into the register? Whereas in the second example their is less potential for interruption? Grateful for any comments on this.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, when the tmpreg is written back in it will overwrite the whole register. Interruption can actually occur in several places in the second example as you're doing read->modify->write operations. You could read->[interrupt]->modify->[another interrupt]->write and any of those interrupts could make changes to the register that you're modifying.

Comment: @Tom thanks. I was thinking that having to do the explicit read (as per first example) would be less tolerant to interruption, as there are other operations on the tmpreg inbetween the initial read and write. However, as you say, the second example has multiple reads., which as others have mentioned is non-optimal.